# How many numbers from 1 to 99,999 contain exactly one of each of the digits 2,3,4,5?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many numbers from 1 to 99,999 (in their ordinary decimal representations) contain exactly one of each of the digits 2,3,4,5?

I'm trying to solve this problem using rules of probability/counting; so far I have tried to use the rules of permutation.

Comment: (1) What have you tried? (2) Do you mean the numbers have exactly one 2 in them, exactly one 3 in them, exactly one 4 in them, and exactly one 5 in them?

Comment: 1) I have tried to use the rules of permutation. 2) yes.

Comment: Please show us your attempts to calculate the number of four-digit and five-digit numbers that contain exactly one of each of the digits $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$.

Answer (score 2):

There are $4!$ ways of permuting the digits 2,3,4,5

For each permutation there are 5 places to put it the other digit

There are 6 choices for what the other digit should be.

You are guaranteed that all five digits are distinct, so you don't have to worry about double-counting.

so $$N=6\times 5 \times 4! = 6!=720$$

Comment: Nope, too big. You counted 02345 when you shouldn't.

Comment: If leading zeros are not ordinary you could just subtract $4!$ from my answer.

Comment: (1) They're not ordinary. (2) Then your answer is correct.

Comment: You can consider a five-digit string with a leading zero since those correspond to the four-digit numbers satisfying the condition.

Comment: That's right, the question doesn't demand that you have 5 digits

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at 5-digit numbers where the digits 2, 3, 4, and 5 appear exactly once each. The fifth digit must be 0, 1, 6, 7, 8, or 9. There are two cases to consider:

(a) The fifth digit is 0. That means you have 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, which you want to put in some order. You can't put 0 first, so you have 4 choices for the first digit, 4 for the next, 3, then 2, then 1, so there are $4\cdot 4!$ numbers that contain 0.

(b) The fifth digit is 1, 6, 7, 8, or 9. There are 5 choices here. You can order the digits in any of the $5!$ possible ways. So there are $5\cdot 5!$ choices here.

Now you add the numbers together, because we split the problem into cases. Answer: $4\cdot4! + 5\cdot 5! = 696$.

**ADDENDUM**: I was counting 5-digit numbers, which is not actually what you want. There are also  4-digit numbers that you want to count, and there are $4!=24$ of them. So the total is really $696+24=720$.

Answer (score 1):

We can pad with initial $0$'s so that everybody has $5$ digits. That makes no difference to the answer.

We can place the $2$ in $5$ ways. For each way, we can place the $3$ in $4$ ways. For each way of placing the $2$ and $3$, the $4$ can be placed in $3$ ways, and then the $5$ can be placed in $5$ ways.

The remaining digit can be chosen in $6$ ways, for a total of $(5)(4)(3)(2)(6)$.